# Это бессоюзное сложное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение, бессоюзное

***Но я вижу, вам это не подходит*** (бессоюзное сложное предложение).

Союза действительно нет, и предложение сложное. Но разве в БСП с изъяснительными отношениями ставится запятая?

Сложное предложение похоже на СПП с пропущенным союзом. Как правильно определить его вид?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В полном академическом справочнике и в справочнике Розенталя есть такое примечание.

При глаголах, выражающих чувственное восприятие, возможна и постановка запятой — если пишущий не намерен выразить предупреждение: **Слышу, с полей донеслась жалейка, ветер дыханье полей принес (Лис).**

Думаю, ваш пример можно отнести к этому пункту правила.

Comment: Да, нашла это правило: http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg129.php  § 129.  Спасибо, Серж.